# why the onClickListener dont work?

Tags: eclipse, button, view, onclick, onclicklistener

I wrote this code and I want to use it when the user decide to exit my application.
when I activate it Eclipse telling me that there is an error with the yes button. This line is the problematic:`yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`
and this is the full code:
`@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        final Dialog exitDialog = new Dialog(this);
        exitDialog.setTitle("Exit");
        exitDialog.setContentView(R.layout.exit_dialog);`

```
    yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            exitDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });

    exitDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: where is yes button inside R.layout.exit_dialog?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible problems
1st because of `this` keyword it is referencing the current Dialog class so give your `ClassName.this`

2nd because of `final` keyword remove the final keyword and give the listener in `onCreate(Bundle SavedInstances) method`

Answer (score 0):

How did you initialize the button yes? The recommended way is:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_quit)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   }
               });

Dialog dialog =  builder.create();
dialog.show();
}
```

You can also refer to [Android dialog guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Answer (score -1):

You should use

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                exitDialog.dismiss();
        finish()
            }
        });
```

instead of OnClickListener.
Another (better) option is to use JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...);

Comment: eclipse doesnt recognice this ActionListener... cant import it or anything else

Comment: The listener is for Swing, not Android.